# List of Tersoff potentials?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry

I would like to know some GNU libraries or lists of downloadable Tersoff potentials. I couldn't find that many of them, and I also would like to know if there is a reason as to why this is the case.

Comment: I think that you can improve your question. For example: what are "Tersoff potentials"? where are you planning to use these potentials?.

Comment: In a fast search I found that LAMMPS have Tersoff potentials in it: http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/pair_tersoff.html

Comment: @nicoguaro LAMMPS only has about 12 Tersoff potentials, 5 of them are for SiC. I am familiar with them, although I do not have in depth knowledge. They are similar to force fields, but they are a bit more complicated. More difficult to determine parameters. I need the potentials to simulate amorphous crystals.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Atomistica](https://github.com/Atomistica/atomistica) ([GitHub](https://github.com/Atomistica/atomistica)) which is GPL-2.0 licenced.

It certainly contains [an implementation of Tersoff potentials](https://github.com/Atomistica/atomistica/blob/master/doc/potentials.md), unfortunately, I am not an expert in molecular dynamics and cannot say if that is enough for your simulation.

This library currently has built-in implementations of the following potentials that employ Tersoff's functional form:

- [Tersoff, 1989](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.39.5566)
- [Goumri-Said, 2004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chemphys.2004.03.030)
- [Matsunaga, 2000](http://dx.doi.org/10.1143/JJAP.39.L48)

and you can upload yours.

Regarding the list of potentials:

[Interatomic Potentials Repository](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/potentials/) contains many files, and at least [some seem to have](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/potentials/system/C-Si/) keywords *amorphous* and/or *crystal* in their descriptions.